# Which Commands do I have to use SSD1306 over I²C?

Tags: c, linux, arduino, raspberry-pi, i2c

I want to create a simple linux driver for the SSD1306 that I have connected to my Raspberry Pi over I²C.

Before I start coding, I want to get to know the device and which commands I have to send. I use the i2c-tools for linux to test my commands. I studied some Arduino projects and the datasheet of the SSD1306, but I could only recreate a few commands on the commandline:

Initializing the device: `i2cset -y 1 0x3c 0xAE 0x20 0x10 0xb0 0xc8 0x00 0x10 0x40 0x81 0x7f 0xa1 0xa6 0xa8 0x3f 0xa4 0xd3 0x00 0xd5 0xf0 0xd9 0x22 0xda 0x12 0xdb 0x20 0x8d 0x14 0xaf i`

Send data to the device's memory: `i2cset -y 1 0x3c 0x40 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF i`
This fills some Pixels from the current position to the right.

Jumping to the upper left pixels: `i2cset -y 1 0x3c 0xb0 0x00 0x10 i`
This didn't always work :(

0x3c is the address of my SSD1306 device

I would be glad if someone could tell me some more commands or knows where I can find a good example or tutorial with comments.

Thanks,

p0kR

Comment: All of the commands should be listed in the datasheet. If some are not there, then they either not exist or you have a bad datasheet.

Comment: Questions about where to find the manual of displays, tutorials or other off-site resources are off-topic here.

Comment: I have a datasheet, but i have problems to find the correct commands. Nobody asked for a datasheet

Comment: And a good example/tutorial, which I asked for could also be an answer, to a completely different question about the same device. And maybe You can't find it because the interesting part for me is just a little part of it. But I'm sorry if my question offended someone in some way ✌

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's an extended example inspired by https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/390980:

```
function display_off() {
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xAE  # Display OFF (sleep mode)
sleep 0.1
}

function init_display() {
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xA8  # Set Multiplex Ratio
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x3F    # value
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xD3  # Set Display Offset
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x00    # no vertical shift
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x40  # Set Display Start Line to 000000b
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xA1  # Set Segment Re-map, column address 127 ismapped to SEG0
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xC8    # Set COM Output Scan Direction, remapped mode. Scan from COM7 to COM0
#i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xC0   # Set COM Output Scan Direction, remapped mode. Scan from COM7 to COM0
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xDA  # Set COM Pins Hardware Configuration
#i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x12   # Alternative COM pin configuration, Disable COM Left/Right remap
#i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x2    # Sequential COM pin configuration,  Disable COM Left/Right remap
#i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x22   # Sequential COM pin configuration,  Enable Left/Right remap  (8pixels height)
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x32    # Alternative COM pin configuration, Enable Left/Right remap   (4pixels height)
#i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x81 # Set Contrast Control
#i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xCF   # value, 0x7F max.
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xA4  # display RAM content
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xA6  # non-inverting display mode - black dots on white background
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xD5  # Set Display Clock (Divide Ratio/Oscillator Frequency)
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x80    # max fequency, no divide ratio
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x8D  # Charge Pump Setting
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x14    # enable charge pump
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x20  # page addressing mode
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x20    # horizontal addressing mode
#i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x21   # vertical addressing mode
#i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x22   # page addressing mode
}

function display_on() {
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0xAF  # Display ON (normal mode)
sleep 0.001
}

function reset_cursor() {
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x21  # set column address
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x00  #   set start address
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x7F  #   set end address (127 max)
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x22  # set page address
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x00  #   set start address
i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x00 0x07  #   set end address (7 max)
}

display_off
init_display
display_on
reset_cursor

# fill screen
for i in $(seq 1024)
do
   i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x40 0xff
done

reset_cursor

# clear screen
for i in $(seq 1024)
do
   i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x40 0x0
done

reset_cursor

# draw a pattern
for i in $(seq 146)
do
    for i in 1 4 16 64 16 4 1
    do
        i2cset -y 0 0x3c 0x40 $i
    done
done
```

it is quite slow but works. tested with 128x32 oled display + raspberry pi 1.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was looking for, thank you very much. I'll try that tomorrow